# So, "How do..look" is for positive expressions & "What do..look like" for neutral & negative ones, right?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

[This site](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv334.shtml) says:

> Here the How…? form is sometimes associated more with positive
>   features and the What...like? form more with neutral or negative
>   features:
>
> How does she look? ~ Fantastic! That outfit really suits her.
>
> What does she look like? ~ As if she hasn't bought any new clothes in
>   the last twenty years.

*Would you think there is a distinction between "**How do..look**" & "**What do..look like**"?*

Comment: This US English speaker doesn't really think there's much of a distinction like that.  It seems like a really artificial distinction that doesn't match up with how people actually speak.  I can easily imagine a conversation like "*How does he look?*  Not good.  I don't think he will survive until tomorrow."  Or "*What does she look like?*  She's a tall, attractive woman who dresses in the latest fashions."

Answer (score 2):

"How does *X* look?" is for *value* judgments, negative or positive. "How does she look?" "Just awful!"

"What does *X* look like?" is asking for a physical description, not an opinion of the overall look. "What does she look like?" "She's a tall, dark woman in a black dress."